# Why can I not publish an item display template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, publishing, display-template

I have built an item display template which I have added to the contents web part folder in the masterpage gallery.

I need to publish this template - When I try to select the item (or any other item in the masterpage gallery) the ribbon is greyed out. I am a global admin, even gave myself explicit permissions of full control to this masterpage library. I can upload/delete items without an issue.
Am I missing something?

[image]

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got this to work was to take versioning off the masterpage library so users with read access could technically read the files - not the best solution but one which works

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues caused by either browser version or security settings. Though if that's you issue, you would probably see it in every library.